# Elasticsearch query by equivalent words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ES index where I store companies indexed by name. Is there any way so I can search by similar words ?

For example I have the name "Discount Pets & Supplies" and I want to also be able to query like "Discount Pets and Supplies", so basically I'm asking if there is a way to mark "&" as equivalent to "and".

Thank you,
Teodor

Answer (score 2):

Yes, during the analysis phase when you are indexing documents you can define synonyms using a Synonym Token Filter:

> **Synonym Token Filter**
>
> The synonym token filter allows to easily handle synonyms during the
>   analysis process. Synonyms are configured using a configuration file.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

In your specific case, however, you will need to be careful about what other analysis is being done as the & symbol may get stripped out.